# Image processing and video recording using Javacv and Android Camera2 Api

Tags: android, video, javacv, android-camera2

I have created an Android application which will process each frame by adding application icon to the frame available and then will record that modified frame bitmap in video using JavaCV FFMPEGFrameRecorder. I m using imagereader surface and get new frames inside ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener, imageformat is JPEG. My application works fine as required except 2 of the devices, Panasonic P50 and Galaxy Note Edge. In both this devices the final file generated is only audio and not contains any video as i see OnImageAvailableListener is never called.

Here is the code for initializing FFMPEGFrameRecorder:-

```
recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(videoFileName, videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight(), 1);
recorder.setVideoMetadata("rotate", rotation);
recorder.setFormat("mp4");
recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
recorder.setVideoCodec(28);
recorder.setFrameRate(20);
recorder.setVideoOption("preset", "veryfast");
recorder.setVideoQuality(1);
```

Primarily i predicted problem can be video resolution i.e. maximum supported is 1280X720 px for the media format H.264 (mp4) as per this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations), but after fixing video resolution too it is not working only on this two devices.